TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'numberOfCakes')
I am beginner to React and Redux
I am trying to learn Redux with React.
I have created a store in store.js as below -
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;

const BUY_CAKE = "BUY_CAKE";

function buyCake() {
  return {
    type: BUY_CAKE,
  };
}

const initialState = {
  numberOfCakes: 25,
};

const cakeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_CAKE:
      return {
        ...state,
        numberOfCakes: state.numberOfCakes - 1,
      };
  }
};

const store = createStore(cakeReducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("updated State: ", store.getState());
});

// store.dispatch(buyCake());

export { buyCake, store };

And my component is like this -
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { buyCake } from "./redux/store";

class CakeContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
      console.log("props: ", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>No of cakes = {this.props.numberOfCakes}</h2>
        <button>Buy Cake</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// take redux state -> retruns an object
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    numberOfCakes: state.numberOfCakes,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    buyCake: () => dispatch(buyCake()),
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CakeContainer);


`
The problem I am facing is that,
when I am not using dispatch() at least once in the store.js file, I am getting this error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'numberOfCakes')
See Error Here
If I use dispatch() at least once in store.js file, then this error goes away.
Error Vanished after dispatch
Can anyone please tell why is this happening ??

Since you are just starting out learning Redux then I highly recommend starting from current, modern Redux using Redux-Toolkit. The code you are using is extremely outdated (like by half a decade). In the meantime, can you [edit] to include a more complete and accurate [mcve] of the code you are working with? What does "If I use dispatch() at least once in store.js file, then this error goes away" mean exactly? Please show us. The only issue I see in the code is that the cakeReducer reducer function doesn't return a state value for all logical paths.

this error because you forgot to add the default case in reducer
the code will like this.
switch (actions.type) {
    case BUY_CAKE_TYPE:
      return {
        numberOfCake: state.numberOfCake - 1,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }


Got it, thank youuu!!
